# Find similar records in R

Tags: r

I have the following columns in my table: surname, first name, postcode, Street ....
I found the duplicates in my data table with:

```
duplicate_indexes <- which(duplicated(my_data[c('surname', 'first_name')]),)
duplicates <- my_data[duplicate_indexes,]
```

Currently under duplicates I have only records which have exactly the same Information in each column of my data table (surname, first name, postcode, street are exactly the same) .

Now I would like also to find the records from my data table, which have similarities, e.g. surname **or** first name are the same **and** postcode is also the same. how can I do that?

Example Data table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3cXu.png)

Comment: Please share reproducible data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to identify those duplicated rows only using the function `duplicated`.

Here is a toy dataset.

```
first_name <- c("George", "John", "John", "George", "George", "Franklin", "Theodore", "Abraham", "Grover", "William", "William", "John")
surname <- c("Washington", "Adams", "Kennedy", "Bush", "Bush", "Roosevelt", "Roosevelt", "Lincoln", "Cleveland", "Taft", "McKinley", "Tyler")
postcode <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2)
uspres <- data.frame(first_name = first_name, surname = surname, postcode = postcode)
```

Then, one can create 3 vectors that are `TRUE` if the surname is duplicated, if the first name is duplicated, and if the post code is duplicated.

```
surname_dup <- duplicated(uspres['surname']) | duplicated(uspres['surname'], fromLast = TRUE)
first_name_dup <- duplicated(uspres['first_name']) | duplicated(uspres['first_name'], fromLast = TRUE)
postcode_dup <- duplicated(uspres['postcode']) | duplicated(uspres['postcode'], fromLast = TRUE)
```

These vectors can then be used in logical statements, like the one you are looking for.

```
flag <- uspres[(first_name_dup | surname_dup) & postcode_dup, ]
```

|  | first_name | surname | postcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | John | Adams | 2 |
| 3 | John | Kennedy | 2 |
| 4 | George | Bush | 3 |
| 5 | George | Bush | 3 |
| 6 | Franklin | Roosevelt | 4 |
| 7 | Theodore | Roosevelt | 4 |
| 12 | John | Tyler | 2 |